# Is it possible to use iOS 13 system fonts in React Native?

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, uifont, typography

I'd like to use new system fonts available since iOS 13 in my React Native app. In particular, I need **rounded**, **serif** and **monospaced** ones. On the native side it is done using `UIFontDescriptor.SystemDesign` https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/227/?time=142

On React Native side we can use `{ fontFamily: 'System' }` with `StyleSheet` but it only gives the default sans-serif design.

Is it possible to use some Swift code to modify the font descriptor of a Text component? Or should I file an issue in React Native repo with a feature request?

Comment: Are you trying to use it for Android as well, or just in your iOS App? Also can you share an example of one of the fonts that satisfies those requirements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React Native doesn't use `UIFontDescriptor` with the specified design on iOS but you can use next runtime hackery technique - "Method Swizzling" to intercept the systems call to `UIFont` and return a needed one but it should be implemented in ObjC.

Just add this ObjC code to your XCode project:

```objectivec
// UIFont+SystemDesign.m

#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation UIFont (SystemDesign)

+ (void)load {
  static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
  dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    Class class = object_getClass((id)self);
    
    SEL originalSelector = @selector(fontWithName:size:);
    Method originalMethod = class_getClassMethod(class, originalSelector);
    
    SEL swizzledSelector = @selector(_fontWithName:size:);
    Method swizzledMethod = class_getClassMethod(class, swizzledSelector);
    
    BOOL didAddMethod = class_addMethod(class, originalSelector, method_getImplementation(swizzledMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(swizzledMethod));
    if (didAddMethod) {
      class_replaceMethod(class, swizzledSelector, method_getImplementation(originalMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(originalMethod));
    }
    else {
      method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod);
    }
  });
}

#pragma mark - Method Swizzling

+ (UIFont *)_fontWithName:(NSString *)fontName size:(CGFloat)fontSize {
  NSString* const systemRounded = @"System-Rounded";
  NSString* const systemSerif = @"System-Serif";
  NSString* const systemMonospaced = @"System-Monospaced";
  
  NSArray* fonts = @[systemRounded, systemSerif, systemMonospaced];
  
  if ([fonts containsObject:fontName]) {
    if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
      NSDictionary* designs = @{systemRounded : UIFontDescriptorSystemDesignRounded,
                              systemSerif : UIFontDescriptorSystemDesignSerif,
                              systemMonospaced : UIFontDescriptorSystemDesignMonospaced};
      
      UIFontDescriptor *fontDescriptor = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:fontSize].fontDescriptor;
      fontDescriptor = [fontDescriptor fontDescriptorWithDesign: designs[fontName]];
      return [UIFont fontWithDescriptor:fontDescriptor size:fontSize];
    }
    else {
      return [UIFont systemFontOfSize:fontSize];
    }
  }
  
  return [self _fontWithName:fontName size:fontSize];
}

@end
```

Then you can use 'System-Rounded', 'System-Serif' and 'System-Monospaced' fonts into your React Native files:

```js
export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.systemDefault}>Default</Text>
      <Text style={styles.systemRounded}>Rounded</Text>
      <Text style={styles.systemSerif}>Serif</Text>
      <Text style={styles.systemMonospaced}>Monospaced</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  systemDefault: {
    fontFamily: 'System',
    fontSize: 20,
  },
  systemRounded: {
    fontFamily: 'System-Rounded',
    fontSize: 20,
  },
  systemSerif: {
    fontFamily: 'System-Serif',
    fontSize: 20,
  },
  systemMonospaced: {
    fontFamily: 'System-Monospaced',
    fontSize: 20,
  },
});
```

Comment: how does RN creates and uses fonts then? I would like to enable OpenType features. Would Swizzling be the only way?

Comment: @philk RN uses iOS SDK to work with fonts and the legal way - make your RN Native component to support the OS level features or try to find existed ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can't specify a font variant of a system font in React Native. You can download and use the font as a custom font. [1]

I would recommend exporting a  component from a utils/primitives files and setting the styles of that component to use the custom font.

```
// Text.js
import {Text} from 'react-native'
export const Text = () => <Text style={{fontFamily: 'customFontFamily'}} />;



// App.js
import {View} from 'react-native'
import {Text} from './Text'

const App = () => {
return (
  <View>
    <Text>Hello World</Text>
  </View>
 )
}'

export default App;
```

[1] https://gist.github.com/parshap/cf9cf0388d55a044004e5e78fa317b39

Comment: I worry Apple might have an issue with loading their font as a custom font?

Comment: I am not familiar with the licensing of the fonts. Available for download directly from apple https://developer.apple.com/fonts/

Comment: From the San Fransisco font license "You may not embed the Apple Font in any software programs or other products. Except as expressly provided for herein, you may not use the Apple Font to, create, develop, display or otherwise distribute any documentation, artwork, website content or any other work product." So you can not bundle them in your React Native app. You'll need to use the system font alias as described in other answers.